# Floating Panels in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, dockpanel

I am working on an angular application which needs a dock-able panel, I have searched for controls online, but they are hard to use and break our screens to some extent, so I am thinking of creating a dock panel from scratch that has floating widgets when detached should be floating and drag-able, my main questions is how to go about making a floating panel using css and angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview

here above is link which i found , it might be fulfill your requirements.

Thank You